# invalid argument error in cudaMemcpy from device to host

Tags: cuda, gpu

I am new to CUDA/GPU and I am having problems copying data from my device back to the host. I am developing for Jetson TK1 with CUDA Toolkit 6.5. It builds successfully, but gives an error during runtime. My code is below:

```
//main.cu
void allocate(double* const d_inputCurrent, double* signal, double* const d_outputCurrent, const size_t size);

int main () {
    int data_length = 1024000;
    const int length=512;
    const size_t size= length;

    double signalA[length], signalB[length], signalC[length];

for (int i=0; i<data_length; i++)
{

    double *d_inputCurrentIa, *d_inputCurrentIb, *d_inputCurrentIc;
    double *d_outputCurrentIa, *d_outputCurrentIb, *d_outputCurrentIc;

    if(i==0)
    {
        for(int k=0; k<length; k++)
        {
            signalA[k]=v_ia[k];
            signalB[k]=v_ib[k];
            signalC[k]=v_ic[k];
        }
        i=length-1;
    }
    else
    {
        //allocate memory in GPU and kernel call for phase A
        allocate(d_inputCurrentIa, signalA, d_outputCurrentIa, size);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize(); checkCudaErrors(cudaGetLastError());

        checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(signalA, d_outputCurrentIa, sizeof(double) * size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
        signalA[length-1]=v_ia[i];

        //allocate memory in GPU and kernel call for phase B
        allocate(d_inputCurrentIb, signalB, d_outputCurrentIb, size);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize(); checkCudaErrors(cudaGetLastError());

        checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(signalB, d_outputCurrentIb, sizeof(double) * size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
        signalB[length-1]=v_ib[i];

        //allocate memory in GPU and kernel call for phase C;
        allocate(d_inputCurrentIc, signalC, d_outputCurrentIc, size);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize(); checkCudaErrors(cudaGetLastError());

        checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(signalC, d_outputCurrentIc, sizeof(double) * size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
        signalC[length-1]=v_ic[i];

        //memory cleaning
        checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(d_inputCurrentIa));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(d_inputCurrentIb));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(d_inputCurrentIc));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(d_outputCurrentIa));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(d_outputCurrentIb));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(d_outputCurrentIc));
    }
```

And my kernel and function are simple, they are just moving the array elements to the left each time:

```
__global__ void allocate_kernel(double* const d_in, double* const d_out, const size_t size) {

    __shared__ double shared[512];

    int tid = threadIdx.x;

    if(tid < size)
    shared[tid] = d_in[tid];
    __syncthreads();

    if(tid < size-1)
    d_out[tid]=shared[tid+1];
    __syncthreads();

}


void allocate(double* const d_inputCurrent, double* signal, double* const d_outputCurrent, const size_t size) {

    const dim3 blockSize(512);
    const dim3 gridSize(1);

    checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(0));

    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&d_inputCurrent, sizeof(double) * size));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&d_outputCurrent, sizeof(double) * size));

    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemset(d_outputCurrent, 0, sizeof(double) * size));

    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(d_inputCurrent, signal, sizeof(double) * size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    allocate_kernel<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_inputCurrent, d_outputCurrent, size);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize(); checkCudaErrors(cudaGetLastError());
}
```

This is a small part of my doctoral thesis, I was practicing CUDA with this code, I know it is not so meaningful for now, but I couldn't move any further because I am so stuck with this problem. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, you cannot pass a pointer to a function by value, have that function modify the *pointer*, and then expect the modification of that pointer to show up in the calling environment:

```
double *d_inputCurrentIa, *d_inputCurrentIb, *d_inputCurrentIc;
double *d_outputCurrentIa, *d_outputCurrentIb, *d_outputCurrentIc;

...
    //allocate memory in GPU and kernel call for phase A

// at this point, d_inputCurrentIa and d_outputCurrentIa are pointing to nothing
    allocate(d_inputCurrentIa, signalA, d_outputCurrentIa, size);
// allocate modified those pointers internally, but the modified values don't show up here
    cudaDeviceSynchronize(); checkCudaErrors(cudaGetLastError());

    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(signalA, d_outputCurrentIa, sizeof(double) * size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
// therefore you will get an error here, because d_outputCurrentIa still points to nothing
```

There are a variety of ways to make this work.  One approach is to pass the *address* of the pointers you wish to modify and use:

```
void allocate(double** d_inputCurrent, double* signal, double **d_outputCurrent, const size_t size);

double *d_inputCurrentIa, *d_inputCurrentIb, *d_inputCurrentIc;
double *d_outputCurrentIa, *d_outputCurrentIb, *d_outputCurrentIc;

...
    //allocate memory in GPU and kernel call for phase A
    allocate(&d_inputCurrentIa, signalA, &d_outputCurrentIa, size);
...
void allocate(double** d_inputCurrent, double* signal, double** d_outputCurrent, const size_t size) {

    const dim3 blockSize(512);
    const dim3 gridSize(1);

    checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(0));

    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)d_inputCurrent, sizeof(double) * size));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)d_outputCurrent, sizeof(double) * size));

    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemset(*d_outputCurrent, 0, sizeof(double) * size));

    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(*d_inputCurrent, signal, sizeof(double) * size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    allocate_kernel<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(*d_inputCurrent, *d_outputCurrent, size);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize(); checkCudaErrors(cudaGetLastError());
}
```

Notes:

1. Not sure why you would mark those pointers `const`.  They are not in any way `const` (the function will modify the pointer *value* as well as the data it is pointing to.)
2. Coded in browser.  You may have to fix some other things up.  Since you haven't provided a complete code to work with, I haven't provided a complete code either.  But this should be a roadmap.
3. Allocating in functions can be a memory leak waiting to happen.  You might want to give this some thought.  Be sure to have a plan to free up those pointers if you will be reusing them or creating a lot of them.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply @Robert. Obviously I am not familiar with coding (especially _pointers_:) ), just trying to figure out some GPU programming in a very little amount of time. I followed your steps and it worked, but this time I got "bus error" during runtime. Everything you said was right, so I removed `const`, allocated everything in main function and free the pointers at the end. Now it works quite well. I can post the improved answer if someone is interested.